# How to check if a certain task is running?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I tried the following:

```
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop
task1 = asyncio.create_task(any_coroutine())

if task1 in asyncio.all_tasks(loop):
    do something...
```

but it never meets the if condition. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

According to [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), as `create_task` calls `get_running_loop` you don't have to get event loop - assuming you're already running event loop so `get_running_loop()` didn't raise following error which your code does:

`RuntimeError: no running event loop`

---

Instead, try new `async` and `await` keywords, loop arguments will be deprecated on python 3.10 so it's better move if you're learning asyncio.

Following example will meet condition in `if` block correctly.

```py
import asyncio

async def my_coro():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(my_coro())

    if task in asyncio.all_tasks():
        print('Task found!')
    else:
        print('Missed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```